# Duplicating data frame rows by freq value in same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with names by type and their frequencies.  I'd like to expand this data frame so that the names are repeated according to their name-type frequency.
For example, this:

```
> df = data.frame(name=c('a','b','c'),type=c(0,1,2),freq=c(2,3,2))
name type freq
1    a    0    2
2    b    1    3
3    c    2    2
```

would become this:

```
> df_exp
name type
1    a    0
2    a    0
3    b    1
4    b    1
5    b    1
6    c    2
7    c    2
```

Appreciate any suggestions on a easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `rep` to "expand" your `data.frame` rows:

```
df[rep(sequence(nrow(df)), df$freq), c("name", "type")]
#     name type
# 1      a    0
# 1.1    a    0
# 2      b    1
# 2.1    b    1
# 2.2    b    1
# 3      c    2
# 3.1    c    2
```

---

And there's a function `expandRows` in the [splitstackshape](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splitstackshape/index.html)  package that does exactly this. It also has the option to accept a vector specifying how many times to replicate each row, for example:

```
expandRows(df, "freq")
```